# SaveFileDialog ignores InitialDirectory

Tags: c#, wpf, savefiledialog

If I use:

```
SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
string StartDir = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%Public%\\Documents");
dlg.InitialDirectory = StartDir;

if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
}
```

The dialog opens to the Current User's Documents folder instead...  I have verified that `StartDir = "C:\Users\Public\Documents"`. Is there any way to force it to start in `"C:\Users\Public\Documents"`?

The data being saved should be visible to all users on the machine...

This is a c# WPF Desktop Application using .NET 4.7.1.

Comment: That's just Microsoft applying the boss-override-switch.  They got way too many support calls from customers losing important documents that were not backed-up.  Allowing users to overwrite each others files is not a feature that ever makes admins and OS creators happy.  There might be a registry key that disables this, superuser.com tends to be the right place to find it.  Iffy, Google doesn't help much.

Comment: Not that it helps with your problem but you shouldn't hard-code folder name strings like "Documents".  Your code may not work on non-English systems and won't work if Microsoft choose to change the name of the folder.  Use something like `string StartDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);` instead

Comment: I actually started out using dlg.InitialDirectory =  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments); but I ended up hard coding it in an attempt to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the [`InitialDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx) also requires to set the [`RestoreDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.restoredirectory.aspx) to `true` to work like exprected.

```
dlg.InitialDirectory = StartDir;
dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
```

Also think about direct initialization of these properties:

```
SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog()
{
    InitialDirectory = StartDir,
    RestoreDirectory = true
};
```

Comment: Not working. Its opening `Libraries\Documents` in my machine Windows 7 OS.

Comment: Well this looks like a problem of the `ExpandEnvironmentVariables` and not of the dialog by itself for me.

Answer (score 0):

to work you need set property `AutoUpgradeEnable = false`.

Comment: Setting AutoUpgradeEnable = false did not make a difference